Can't install Ubuntu
I mounted the Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS ISO on a stick and when I choose it from the boot manager the GRUB menu doesn't show up, I get a black screen and nothing happens. If I do the same thing with the same stick from another PC it starts correctly and I have no problems. When i click Pause it says "Pause key has been pressed! Press any other key to continue!!". Please I need help.

What brand/model system? What video card/chip? UEFI or BIOS? And did you create live installer on flash drive in that mode? Some UEFI have extra security settings to prevent USB boot, check UEFI settings to allow USB boot or full USB support. Dual boot with Windows or full install? Is Windows fast startup on or Windows bitlocker on? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Did you mount the stick, or did you boot to the stick after writing the ISO to the stick with something like Balena Etcher?  We need a little bit of details here to help.

You do mention a release (24.04.1 LTS) but don't say which product (Server? Desktop? was it a flavor?), which architecture as there are many ISO choices that provide a live system. Did you verify the media check completed on the other machine? and was it different hardware?  How as ISO written? as if reformatted due ISO write it can fail to boot on certain hardware, so a clone or direct write is best for all hardware.

I have disactivated the fast startup. It's Ubuntu Desktop. And also i said that it's not a problem with the USB but with the pc because with the other one works fine

Unless the other machine has identical hardware to the current PC; your logic behind testing the USB is flawed, as Ubuntu Desktop contains many different components that will only be used for specific hardware...  Your last comment logic assumes both machines have identical hardware - is that correct?

This question is similar to: Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please tell us details about the computer: Brand name and model and about the graphics chip/card (also brand name and model). These details will help us help you.

I never said that the hardware was the same, it's similar though. I wanted to say that the problem isn't with the USB but with the pc, because the USB works only with one of them. The processor of the pc that doesn't work is Inter Celeron J4105 with integrated graphics, 12 gb of RAM

This computer seems to be 'new and powerful enough' for the current Ubuntu. There might be problems because the UEFI-BIOS system does not allow booting into anything else than Windows from the internal drive. Please enter the UEFI-BIOS menu system. Note the current settings and then modify one or more of them: allow boot from USB, turn off secure boot, turn off TPM ... etc, whatever is possible to modify. -- If you tell us the brand name and model of the computer, someone here might know what specific tweak that can make it boot into Ubuntu.

If you have installed the OS to the target computer from a live system on the USB stick and you find that the problem is that the installed system boots to a BlackSOD, I don't have a complete solution, but the first step in identifying the problem involves removing the "quiet splash" feature from your OS.  You will then be able to see error messages on boot that will give you some insight.
You will need to edit the grub file to do this.  Follow the instructions here:
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/boot-linux-command-line-mode
Then look for:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
Remove "quiet splash" and replace with the word "menu":
Then type:
sudo update-grub
Restart the computer and watch for indications as to what is going wrong.  Common problems include video drivers that don't get installed properly leaving you with a black screen.  Trying to boot in Comaptability Mode or Safe Mode can solve the problem temporarily by at least allowing you to see the desktop and fix the driver problem, which will take more research.

I said that i did not install the OS because i can't even access the GRUB menu, so how could i do those commands if I didn't install it?

Well your text wan't clear.  So you didn't install it from the stick.  But if the installation stick works on another computer, then the problem is likely settings on your computer's bios.  Usually security settings like "secure boot enabled" or sometimes efi/bios selectors.  I had a computer that wouldn't install linux because I had chosen "efi/legacy" instead of "efi only" in the bios settings.  I only discovered this by trial and error,  trying all sorts of different bios configurations until it would install.
